# Cordova BLE Connect automatically (without user action) based on device name fails due async execution of ble.scan

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am developing an app using cordova and BLE plugin. I want to connect via BLE automatically to an ESP32 based on a hard coded known device.name without the user needed to press a connect button.

My idea was:

On device ready run the scan:

```
scanForDevices: function(){ 
    ble.scan([], 10, app.onDiscoverDevice, app.onError); 
    app.getDevIdFromList(); 
},
```

Construct an array with all devices discovered:

```
  onDiscoverDevice: function(device) { 
     deviceList[deviceNr] = [device.name, device.id, device.rssi]; 
     deviceNr = deviceNr + 1 ; 
  },
```

And when the ble.scan function finishes run app.getDevIdFromList() which checks if my device name is in the list and if yes start connecting:

```
getDevIdFromList: function(){ 
   for (var i = 0; i < deviceList.length; i++) 
       { if (deviceList[i][0]== "myDeviceName")
          { myDeviceDetected = "true"; 
            myDeviceId = deviceList[i][1]; 
            app.connect(); 
          } 
       } 
       if (myDeviceDetected == "false"){
           app.onBtDetectionError(); 
       } },
```

The problem seems to be that getDevIdFromList is being called before ble.scan finishes (running async?) resulting in an incomplete or even empty array being processed by getDevIdFromList throwing the onBtDetectionError even when my device is available.

Any idea how to fix this?
thx!

(See also the issue I raised on the BLE plugin github [#597](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central/issues/597) but as the owner pointed out this is more a question for stack overflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since scan is async it makes the logic a bit more complicated.  One way to do this is to wait for the scan to finish, then check the results.

```
connectByName: function(name) {

    const devices = [];

    // scan and save devices to a list
    ble.startScan([], d => devices.push(d));

    // check the list when the scan stop
    setTimeout(() => {
        ble.stopScan();

        const device = devices.filter(d => d.name === name)[0];
        if (device) {
            ble.connect(device.id, app.onConnected, app.onDisconnected);
        } else {
            console.log(`Couldn't find device ${name}`);
        }
    }, 5000);
},
```

This works fine, but you always need to wait for the scan to finish. Even if the scan finds the device immediately, you need to wait for the timeout. Another approach is to filter devices as you are scanning.

```
connectByName: function(name) {

    let scanning = true;

    ble.startScan([], device => {
        if (device.name === name) {
            ble.stopScan();
            scanning = false;
            ble.connect(device.id, app.onConnected, app.onDisconnected);
        } else {
            console.log(`Skipping ${device.name} ${device.id}`);
        }
    });

    // set timer to stop the scan after a while
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (scanning) {
            ble.stopScan(); 
            console.log(`Couldn't find device ${name}`);
        }
    }, 5000);
},
```

The second method is often better since it can connect faster.

If you're only running on Android, and you have the MAC address of the device, you can connect without scanning. (iOS still requires you to scan.)

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    // connect by MAC address on startup
    const MAC_ADDRESS = 'E4:86:1E:4E:5A:FB';
    ble.connect(MAC_ADDRESS, app.onConnected, app.onDisconnected);
},
```

There's also a new autoConnect function that will automatically connect and disconnect whenever the phone is in range of the device. (This doesn't work well on iOS yet.)

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    // Auto connect whenever the device is in range
    const MAC_ADDRESS = 'E4:86:1E:4E:5A:FB';
    ble.autoConnect(MAC_ADDRESS, app.onConnected, app.onDisconnected);
},
```

See https://gist.github.com/don/e423ed19f16e1367b96d04ecf51533cc for complete versions of index.js